# Pattern matching on wild card

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, wildcard

Hello i am trying to pattern match for a *wild card* pattern but I need to "grab" the `wild card`.I am trying to parse a `String` to a `list` of `Maybe Int`.
**INPUT**
`{123,aa,55,66}`
**OUTPUT** 
`[Just 123,Nothing,Just 55.4,Just 66.3]`
So I put together the following method:

**Method**

```
readDataRaw::String->[Maybe Int]
    readDataRaw (x:xs)=go [] [](x:xs) where
            go _ ls []         = ls
            go small big (x:xs)= case x of
                                  '}'    -> big
                                  ','    -> go [] ((readMaybe small::Maybe Int):big)  xs 
                                   c@(_) -> go [] c:small big xs
```

**Error**

```
parse error on input `->'
   |
66 |                                    c@(_) -> go [] c:small big xs
   |                                          ^^
```

How can i use the wild card on the right side of the `->` in my last case ?

Comment: While you should use pattern `c` instead of `c@(_)`, there's nothing wrong with the latter. The real issue in the above code is that `c@(_)` is not indented as the `','` of the previous line, so it is parsed as the continuation of the previous line, as if you wrote a single line `',' -> go [] (....) xs c@(_) -> go [] ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a **variable identifier**, a variable does not specify any pattern, so you can write it like:

```
readDataRaw::String -> [Maybe Int]
readDataRaw (x:xs) = go [] [](x:xs) where
    go _ ls [] = ls
    go small big (x:xs) = case x of
        '}' -> big
        ',' -> go [] ((readMaybe small::Maybe Int):big)  xs 
        c -> go [] c:small big xs
```

The above however has some errors, and incomplete patterns. For example in `readDataRaw` you only specify the `(x:xs)` pattern in the head, whereas it is - strictly speaking - possible that you call the function with an empty list `[]`. It also "clashes" with the `(x:xs)` in the `go` pattern: this is not a problem since Haskell takes the "closest" variable, so the one defined in th3e `go` clause, but it introduces some confusion. In the last case (with the `c`, you als return `go [] c : small big xs`, which will be interpreted as `(go [] c) : small big xs` which does not make much sense. A "refactored" implementation could look like:

```
readDataRaw::String -> [Maybe Int]
readDataRaw = go [] [] where
    go _ ls [] = ls
    go small big (x:xs) = case x of
        '}' -> big
        ',' -> go [] ((readMaybe small::Maybe Int):big)  xs 
        c -> go (c:small) big xs
```

But still, it is a bit "ugly". This is partly because it is unclear *what* you want to do.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: how is `66.3` an `Int`?

Comment: This looks like a classic problem: you aim to do *too* much in a single function. You can make a parser that omits the curly brackets, and splits the input by a comma, next it is only a `map`ping with `readMaybe`.

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo , it really does not matter if it is a `Int` or a `Double`.Initially i wanted to make something that could work on more types..but i let it `Int`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: well as said, I think it might be better to use a tool like `Parsec` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) to specify the "grammar" of your language and thus omitting the curly brackets, and split by a comma. You can then perform a simple `map readMaybe` to any type.

Comment: I wanted to still do some `primitive` operations to get the hang of it before i start `parsec`.Anywho you answered my question regarding `wild pattern`.I was curious  since there are times when i want to further  `branch` that `wild card`.(Something like `case x of t@(t1:t2) - >`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: yes but that is when you specify a data constructor, so a `variablename@(constructor para meters)`.